# angular translateProvider Issue with useLocalStorage

Tags: angularjs

my code:

```
var app =  angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap','ngCookies','pascalprecht.translate'], function($locationProvider) {});

app.config(function ($translateProvider,$translatePartialLoaderProvider){
    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
      urlTemplate:'/ang/src/verbiage/{lang}/{part}.json'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('us-en');
    $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
});
```

**The above code is giving me following error:**
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15-build.2399+sha.ca4ddfa/$injector/unpr?p0…calStorageProvider%20%3C-%20%24translateLocalStorage%20%3C-%20%24translate

**if i remove $translateProvider.useLocalStorage(); page is working file but i need to implement $translateProvider.useLocalStorage() **

in my index.html i included following js files .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/vendor/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/vendor/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/vendor/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

**Please Help**

Answer (score 3):

make sure you have included "`angular-translate-storage-local.min.js`" in your `index.html`.

You can download the file here, https://github.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-storage-local

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working translate provider service:

```
(function(){
/*globals myApp*/
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp').config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        foo : 'hello'
    })
    .translations('tr', {
        foo : 'merhaba'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
}]);
})();
```

If you want to use cookie include this script in your HTML:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js"></script>
```

if you want to use local storage include this script in your HTML:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.js"></script>
```

download link: https://github.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-storage-local

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:  I am not an angular expert.

That said:
Are you missing your injection on app.config?  should your second line read:

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', '$translatePartialLoaderProvider'], 
   function($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider){...
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple thing as storing a user preference this installation is surprisingly complicated.   If you want to use localStorage the angular-translate way then you need to bower install angular-translate-storage-local, angular-cookies and angular-translate-storage-cookies (although some of those dependencies do overlap) and then also ensure you're including the javascript files in the right order in your index.html.

Thus:

```
<!-- angular cookies -->
<script src="lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

<!-- angular translate -->
<script src="lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.min.js"></script>
```