# How to persist selected language in LocalStorage while using Angular-translate?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, angular-local-storage

I am new to [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) in my Angular app.

**Requirement :**

I have to create a multi language application in `AngularJS` where user has an option to set his language. So, for that I have to load translations from files and save that preferred language in `localStorage`.
So that if the user comes again to access the application he will be displayed the previously set language.

**What i have done so far :**

Loaded translations from files by using **`$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader`**

**Code :**

```
var app = angular.module("myLangApp", ['pascalprecht.translate'])
app.config(function($translateProvider) {
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'languages/',
        suffix: '.json'
      });
    $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
});
```

Application works fine if I comment this line:

```
// $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
```

**But if I use it, I am getting this error on the console:**

[image: Console error for the above code.]

I have also included the `angular-translate-storage-local.min.js` file in my `index.html`.But no success.

I have also seen these questions in SO, but they don't help:
[Angular-translate's localStorage: Unknown provider: $translateLocalStorageProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287185/angular-translates-localstorage-unknown-provider-translatelocalstorageprovid)

Any immediate help will be highly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular-translate's localStorage: Unknown provider: $translateLocalStorageProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287185/angular-translates-localstorage-unknown-provider-translatelocalstorageprovid)

Comment: Also include this: https://github.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-storage-cookie

Comment: I think this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364503/angular-translateprovider-issue-with-uselocalstorage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the [documentation](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/10_storages) on storage with angular translate

What you'll soon realize after reading it is that the **angular-translate-storage-local** library is meant to be used together with the **angular-translate-storage-cookie** library. Since local storage is not supported on some of the older browsers (example : IE 7 or below), angular translate want to have a fall back option to use cookies when local storage won't do the trick.

The error is caused by **angular-translate-storage-local** trying to inject its fall back option **angular-translate-storage-cookie**.

To circumvent this problem, you'll want to install **angular-translate-local-cookie**.

Beware that angular-translate-local-cookie tries to inject **ngCookie** which is a library that you'll have to install as well as set the dependency injection for your app. Injection should be

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
```

Also, the wrong ordering of the include files in your index.html can also cause problems for you. The proper order should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my app I also comment `$translateProvider.useLocalStorage();`
but I added

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
  prefix: 'languages/',
  suffix: '.json'
});
```

I have different json files, one for each lang, and with the func

```
$translate.use('fr')
```

I change the ui language
every time that the user change the lang I save it in the local storage and use it on startUp inside the $translate.use

Comment: I agree with you. But my question is different.I want to save the user language in the local storage. so that if user comes again on the app there is no need to select the language again.

Comment: the '$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en')' set the default lang,

Comment: the '$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en')' set the default lang,
you can build a startUp func that will check if there's a saved lang value in the localStorage and will apply it using: '$translate.use(window.localStorage.getItem('CLIENT_LANG'))'
and in another function when the user will decide to change the ui lang you will build:
'changeLang(langKey){
   $translate.use("" + langKey);   
   window.localStorage.setItem('CLIENT_LANG',langKey);
}'

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try to include these two js files into your index page

- angular-translate-storage-local.js
- angular-translate-storage-cookie.js

or(if you use Bower)

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js"></script>
```